# Index was out of range - editing a gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net

I currently have a Gridview that is populated through the selection of a value from the drop down list. Once the value is selected the gridview is populated and I am trying to allow the user to edit values in the gridview using 'RowUpdating' event. However I am trying to update the values in the Gridivew based on the value from the Drop Down list which is 'StockTakeIDNew'.

Here is my c# code.

```
   protected void GridView1_RowUpdating(object sender, GridViewUpdateEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            using (SqlConnection sqlCon = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=(local)\;Initial Catalog=SmallBatch;Integrated Security=True;"))
            {
                sqlCon.Open();
                string query = "UPDATE Stock_Take_Item SET BarQuantity=@BarQuantity, StorageQuantity=@StorageQuantity WHERE StockTakeIDNew =@id";
                SqlCommand sqlCmd = new SqlCommand(query, sqlCon);
                sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@BarQuantity", (GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("barQuantityTxt") as TextBox).Text.Trim());
                sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@StorageQuantity", (GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("storageQuantityTxt") as TextBox).Text.Trim());
                sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", Convert.ToInt32(GridView1.DataKeys[e.RowIndex].Value.ToString()));
                sqlCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

                String query1 = "SELECT Stock_Take.Username, Item.ItemID, Item.ItemDesc, Stock_Take_Item.BarQuantity, Stock_Take_Item.StorageQuantity, Stock_Take.StockTakeIDNew FROM Item INNER JOIN Stock_Take_Item ON Item.ItemID = Stock_Take_Item.ItemID INNER JOIN Stock_Take ON Stock_Take_Item.StockTakeIDNew = Stock_Take.StockTakeIDNew where Stock_Take.StockTakeIDNew = @DATE";

                SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=(local)\;Initial Catalog=SmallBatch;Integrated Security=True;");
                con.Open();
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query1, con);
                DdlUser.SelectedValue.GetType();

                cmd.Parameters.Add("@DATE", SqlDbType.Int).Value = DdlUser.SelectedValue;

                SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                GridView1.DataSource = reader;
                GridView1.DataBind();

            }

        }
```

I am using this code. I basically don't the @ID value to be .DataKeys and instead the value of the SelectedIndexChanged from the DDL.

The code runs except i get the error: 
Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection. Parameter name: index

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is an IndexOutOfRangeException / ArgumentOutOfRangeException and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20940979/what-is-an-indexoutofrangeexception-argumentoutofrangeexception-and-how-do-i-f)

Comment: Unrelated tips: the second SqlConnection seems to be the same as the first: why not just use the first? If not, put it in a using block. SqlCommand is also disposable so the instances should be in using blocks. You may also want to read [can we stop using AddWithValue](https://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/).